# "Ihr Antrag ist abgelehnt" what does it mean and what structure is used?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> Ihr Antrag ist abgelehnt

I think this use present perfect but *ablehnen* doesn't take *sein* and also this isn't passive sentence either because there's no *werden* in this sentence so I can't understand what it means as well as what kind of structure it is.

If it is passive sentence then I think it mean "your proposal/request is refused"

Comment: You are right about the missing *werden*, but this is *Zustandspassiv*.

Comment: Thank, I'm learning on internet so from many link, it only say about passive using werden

Comment: Actually, even though I am a native speaker and had some grammar at school, I would until recently also have claimed that this is not passive, for the same reason as you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This form is called *Zustandspassiv*. You are right that *Vorgangspassiv* would have involved *werden*:

> Ihr Antrag ist abgelehnt worden.

Or:

> Ihr Antrag wurde abgelehnt.

But now that it has been rejected, it *is* in a rejected state:

> Ihr Antrag ist abgelehnt.

Damit ist meine Antwort beendet.

Comment: Hi, so how can people avoid confusion between *Zustandspassiv* and *Perfekt* which require *sein* like *kommen*?

Comment: @aukxn, this confusion can only arise with transitive verbs, and I think that most of them form the *Perfekt* with "haben". Otherwise: With the help of context and common sense.

Comment: @CarstenS Well, as a passiv can only be formed with transitive verbs... ;-) Besides, where is there confusion? I don't get the point?

Comment: @mramosch, ich denke aukxn meint, wenn jemand einen Marathon gelaufen ist (schlechtes Beispiel aus mehreren Gründen, aber mir fällt kein besseres ein), könnte man analog zu dem obigen „der Marathon ist gelaufen“ sagen, und wüsste dann nicht, ob der Marathon selber gelaufen ist oder gelaufen wurde.

Comment: @CarstenS: Nun, wenn der Marathon ***'läuft'***, dann ist das aber auch ein intransitiver Gebrauch des Verbes mit einer anderen Bedeutung...

Comment: @mramosch, ich habe ja auch gesagt, dass es kein Problem ist. Aber die Frage war wohl, wie man „<Substantiv> ist <Partizip Perfekt>“ ansieht, ob es Zustangspassiv im Präsenz oder Aktiv im Perfekt ist.

Comment: Na ja, weil es kein Verb gibt, dass mit absolut identischer Bedeutung sowohl *'transitiv'* und *'intransitiv'* ist... - Und damit ist dann das Problem auch schon gelöst ;-) Or would you say that ***'The show runs on TV...'*** vs. ***'The man runs a marathon...'*** would give you a headache when interpreting the present-tense of 'to run' in english...? And so doesn't german... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It is a passive voice. *Your request **is declined***.

Participle II.

Everything is very logical in German grammar. Since there is *ge* inside the conjugated verb, it is a past form: *ablehnen* - *abgelehnt*.

Here are the conjugations:
http://www.verbformen.de/konjugation/ablehnen.htm

Comment: "Everything is very logic in German." That almost deserves a downvote. ;-)

Comment: @chirlu but it truly is! :-) At least in Grammar. I will do some edits though... ))

Answer (score 1):

While claiming a *Zustandspassiv* formed with *sein* ***is not wrong,*** the construction can also be analysed differently.

*Abgelehnt*, being the past participle of *ablehnen*, can also function as an adjective.

> Der *abgelehnte* Antrag.

Many adjectives can be used both attributively (as in the example I just presented) and predicatively. Predicative usage would be

> Der Antrag ist abgelehnt.

I don’t know why grammar apparantly prefers the *Zustandspassiv* description, but I feel that the predicative adjective description is a lot more logical so I will keep favouring that.

Comment: But it is still -> ***'Der Antrag, der abgelehnt ist/wurde'***...

Comment: @mramosch and what does that change in the argument?

Comment: You are confusing an analysis of *'modes'* or *'voices'* with an analysis of *'tenses'* - They go together - not alternatively... - One thing is being *'attributive/predicative'* - another being *'active/passiv voice'*.

Comment: @mramosch I am not confusing any analysis. My argument is that *abgelehnt* both in your comment’s example an in the OP’s question can be ***both a conjugated verb and an adjective.***

Comment: That's simply wrong! It is a participle in an attributive use-case but ***NOT*** and adjective. Although there are verbs who's participles get grammaticalized to adjectives because of a semantic shift...

Comment: @mramosch Is it? What is the authoritative source you’re using to tell me that I cannot call the word by the function it may have in the sentence?

Comment: It has an attributive function, so has an adjective! Or would you call *'Ein  **vom hundertjährigen Krieg zurückkommender** Armeesoldat...' an adjective only because you are using a relative clause in an attributive position?

Comment: @mramosch Yes, I could. And if I stick to that argument, *vom hundertjährigen Krieg* is no more than an adverbial construction describing the adjective.

Comment: You can analyze any nominal-group down to its phonemes, but that doesn't change the fact that an adjective can not be passiv and a verb can. And I guess you won't deny the very strong passiv-color of ***'Der abgelehnte Antrag'*** (*'der Antrag, der abgelehnt wurde/ist'*) im Gegensatz zu ***'Das schön seiende (schöne) Haus'*** (*'das Haus das geschönt ist/wurde'* ??? oder wie sonst ???)...

Comment: @mramosch I actually do deny that a ‘schön seiendes Haus’ or a ‘schönes Haus’ be any less passive than a ‘abgelehnter Antrag’ — much like a ‘rot gestrichenes Haus’ or a ‘rotes Haus’. All of these combinations do nothing more than describe the noun. None of the nouns did anything active to become ‘abgelehnt’, ‘schön’ or ‘rot’. I don’t see the passiveness strongly at all. I see the description of the noun.

Comment: Well, it is an intrinsic quality or characteristic of the ***'red house'*** to be *'red'* and this says nothing about an activity to become or be 'red', so it can't be passive/active. On the other hand ***'a painted house of whatever color'*** or a ***'painting man'*** is something very *'passive'*  respectively *'active'* because of the attributive participle being derived from a verb...

Comment: QUOTE: *'None of the nouns did anything active to become ‘abgelehnt’* - is simply ***WRONG*** again because 'abgelehnt' is passiv, so how could the noun possibly DO anything active when its attributes tell the contrary. The only thing it DOES is being *'passive'* - so it doesn't do *'being active'* ;-) That would be a contradiction per se - Maybe you should have a look at the Esperanto-Grammar because it qualifies participles into 'active/passive' rather than into 'present/perfect' - This gives a much clearer picture of the functionality as a verb than rather being confused with an adjective.

Comment: @mramosch Which almost concludes a full circle. You have yet to state a proper reason why I must not consider something that describes a noun attributively or predicatively as an adjective. Even if that adjective derives from a verb via a participle.

Comment: Actually let me add another argument into the discussion: If it is a verbal form, why does it correspond with its noun *in gender, number and case* when used attributively just like every other adjective?

Comment: Because of its attributive functionality in that context! Let me ask it the other way round - if they were of the very same kind - like you suggest - why don't correspond adjectives with the way a verb forms passive and active voice? Because they are 'different' by nature - just sometimes used in the same functional environment.

Comment: Actually I think - despite of the different approaches how to define things - this comments shouldn't get deleted because they share a lot of insights on the issue at hand. - Thanks Jan for the solid and qualified discourse ;-)

Comment: Indeed I think that I never heard of *Zustandspassiv* in school. But then I am old (which comes with the advantage of not being as over-excited as some others), so I may simply have forgotten.