# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen „wurde operiert“ und „ist operiert“?

Tags: grammar, passive

Ich kann die Aussage dieser beiden Sätze nicht unterscheiden:

> (1) Der Patient ist operiert.
>
> (2) Der Patient wurde operiert.

Was ist der Unterschied in der Bedeutung?

Comment: Are you sure both sentences are grammatically correct?

Comment: Ähnlich (englisch): https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25403/ihr-antrag-ist-abgelehnt-what-does-it-mean-and-what-structure-is-used – Die Schlüsselwörter sind _Zustandspassiv_ und _Vorgangspassiv_.

Comment: @Alex.S: Ja, sind korrekt. 1. _So, Leute, alles erledigt! Der Patient ist operiert. Jetzt können wir Feierabend machen._ 2. _Der Patient wurde operiert. Es steht noch nicht fest, ob er überleben wird._

Answer (score 4):

**Simple answer:**

**(1)** is more a description of the current **state**---"operiert" is an attribute describing the patient [*Präsenz* + Attribut],

while **(2)** is a description of an **act** done in the past [*Passiv Präteritum*] ---a doctor PERFORMED a surgery.

**More complex answer:**

As your example in the comments is spoken German, you could also argue about (1) "Der Patient ist operiert." being a [linguistic Ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)):

> Der Patient ist operiert (worden).

In this case, it would be *Passiv Perfekt*. So the difference would be a different past tense. Check for the differences between *Präteritum* and *Perfekt*...