# Wie unterscheidet man ein statisches Passiv von einem Perfekt mit »sein«?

Tags: difference, passive, past-participle

Es gibt Verben, die transitiv und intransitiv mit dem Verb *sein* verwendet werden können.
Da sie transitiv verwendet werden können, kann man ein Passiv bilden, darunter ein statisches Passiv. 
**Wie unterscheidet man ein statisches Passiv von einem Perfekt mit *sein?***

Beispiele:

- > Sie sind umgezogen.

  Sind sie selber umgezogen oder sie wurden umgezogen und jetzt sind sie umgezogen?
- > Sie sind verdorben.

  Sind sie von alleine verdorben, oder wurden sie verdorben (dynamisch) und jetzt sind sie verdorben (statisch), oder ist es eine Adjektivkonstruktion?

Wie Hubert angemerkt hat, können Partizip II-Formen eines Verbs (z.B. *verdorben*) auch als Adjektive verwendet werden. Heißt das, dass man dann gar nicht zwischen einem statischen Passiv und einer Adjektiv-Konstruktion unterscheidet? Oder ist das im Grunde das gleiche?

Comment: Lustigerweise können beide Beispiele mit "Sie sind verzogen" ersetzt werden. :) Auch wenn du wahrscheinlich eine andere Wortbedeutung von "verdorben" im Sinn hattest.

Comment: @Em1: Sogar »Sie sind ungezogen« würde sich mit der Bedeutung von »Sie sind verzogen« überlappen.

Comment: Es ist ganz einfach so, dass ein hinreichend gängiges Zustandspassiv mit der Zeit zu einem (echten) Adjektiv mutieren kann. Und weil wir hier einen Übergang beobachten, kann man schlecht sagen, ob wir "noch dort" oder "schon hier" sind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nur der Kontext kann da weiterhelfen. Du erkennst ja selbst, dass »Sie sind verdorben« ohne Kontext viele Deutungen ermöglicht.

Du kannst sogar das Verb als Adjektiv deuten, wodurch »sind« zum Vollverb und der Satz zu einem Aktiv-Satz wird:

> Die Jugendlichen von heute sind furchtbar!
>   Sie sind laut.
>   Sie sind frech.
>   **Sie sind verdorben**.

Beispiele für den Einfluss des Kontext:

Von alleine verdorben:

> Das Haltbarkeitsdatum der Würste wurde um mehr als drei Jahre überschritten.
>   **Sie sind** jetzt **verdorben.**

Durch fremden Einfluss verdorben:

> Hanna und Erika waren früher zwei ganz brave Mädchen. Aber Eugen hat ihnen lauter unanständige Dinge beigebracht und sie auf die schiefe Bahn geführt. Eugen hat die beiden Mädchen verdorben.
>   **Sie sind** jetzt **verdorben.**

Comment: Man muss aber anmerken, dass ob von alleine oder durch fremde Einwirkung, beides Zustandspassiva sind.

Comment: Trotzdem bin ich mir nicht sicher, ob diese Antwort den Kern der Frage wirklich trifft (zumindest so wie ich die Frage verstehe.) Das andere Beispiel ist übrigens das bessere Beispiel und zeigt die Problemstellung sehr gut. "Peter und Maria sind umgezogen und wohnen jetzt in Amerika." versus "Peter und Maria sind umgezogen und gehen gleich ins Bett." Der scheinbar exakt gleiche Satz hat nicht nur eine ganz andere Bedeutung, sondern ist grammatikalisch einmal Perfekt und einmal Passiv. (Wobei im Amerika-Beispiel das auch als Passiv interpretiert werden kann.)

Comment: @Em1: Durch die Änderung des Bedeutung vergleichst du aber zwei verschiedene Wörter (exakter: zwei verschiedene Begriffe die Homonyme sind) miteinander. Dass man damit unterschiedliche Sachen machen kann, liegt auf der Hand. Aber genau das wollte ich vermeiden.

Comment: Mal davon abgesehen, dass ich mir über die Wortherkunft nicht sicher bin und nicht beurteilen kann, ob es wirklich zwei verschiedene Wörter sind, empfinde ich das als irrelevant, vorausgesetzt ich verstehe die Frage richtig. Vielmehr sehe ich das Problem darin, dass man nicht auf Anhieb sehen kann, ob "Sie sind [verb]" Passiv oder Perfekt ist. In Englisch bspw. ist das Perfekt immer mit "have" gebildet und Passiv mit "be" oder "get". "They have moved" vs "They got changed". Missachten wir mal, dass es ein anderes Hauptverb ist, so ist das Hilfsverb ein ausreichender Indikator.

Answer (score -1):

"Sie sind umgezogen" ist perfekt, weil umziehen nicht transitiv ist. Es gibt das als intransitiv (den Wohnort wechseln, oder österreichisch wunderschön "übersiedeln", oder reflexiv "sich umziehen", die Kleidung wechseln.

Generell wäre die passive Form an einem "warden" erkennbar. Sie sind verdorben ist Perfekt. Die passive Form (dynamisch mit Fremdeinwirkung) wäre korrekt "Sie sind verdorben worden".

Comment: »Martha zieht ihre beiden kleinen Töchter um. Wenig später sind sie umgezogen.« Ist das nicht transitiv?

Comment: Erstmal ist "Sie sind verdorben" Passiv nicht Perfekt. Es ist ein Zustandspassiv (Bsp. Die Blume ist verdorben), die Form mit "werden" ist dann Vorgangspassiv (Bsp. "Die Blume ist verdorben worden"). (Zumindest kommt mir gerade kein Kontext in den Sinn, wo der Satz sinnvoll ein Perfekt darstellt. Das erste Beispiel kann je nach Kontext übrigens beides sein.) Des Weiteren geht es denke ich darum, dass "Sie sind [Verb]" nicht augenscheinlich als Perfekt oder Passiv zu identifizieren ist und nach einem Trick gefragt wird, wie man ohne viel Aufwand dies erkennen kann.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Auf Deutsch gibt es ja nichts, was es nicht regional irgendwo gibt. Ich würde aber behaupten, dass in deutschem Hochdeutsch "jemanden umziehen" mindestens nicht üblich ist. Das wäre eher "jemanden anziehen".

Comment: @ErnstSchnell: Das ist mir doch glatt eine eigene Frage wert: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/31324/1487