# Martha zieht ihre zweijährige Tochter um. Korrekt?

Tags: usage, grammaticality

Bei der [Beantwortung einer anderen Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/31292/1487) wurde behauptet, das Verb »*umziehen*« im Sinn von »Kleidung wechseln« könne nicht transitiv verwendet werden. Ich denke aber, dass das doch möglich ist, dass man also durchaus jemand anderen als sich selbst umziehen kann.

Daher meine Frage: Ist der fett hervorgehobene Satz grammatisch korrekt?

> Sina ist Marthas zweijährige Tochter. Die Kleine hat beim Spielen in der Wiese ihre Hose schmutzig gemacht. Als sie ins Haus kommt, bemerkt Martha die Erde- und Grasflecken auf ihrer Hose. Um zu verhindern, dass Sina mit ihrer Hose Erde im Haus verteilt, **zieht Martha ihre Tochter um.** Die schmutzige Hose kommt in die Waschmaschine, und Sina tollt nun in einer sauberen Hose durchs Haus.

Comment: Verständlich ist der Satz natürlich, aber idiomatisch? Ich würde ihn so jedenfalls nicht verwenden und den SV umschreiben.

Comment: Ich finde den Satz vollkommen idiomatisch. Vielleicht muss man ein Elternteil sein, um das zu finden - Als meine Kinder klein waren, hab' ich das 10-mal am Tag gesagt...

Comment: Der einzige Fehler in dem Satz ist in meinen Augen, dass es "Erdflecken" sind und nicht "Erdeflecken" ;)

Comment: @Em1: Gerade bei den Fugenlauten gibt es große regionale Unterschiede. In Deutschland quetscht man beispielsweise, wie ich schon mehrfach erfahren habe, gerne mal ein *s* in den Adventkalender, aber in Österreich kommt im Adventkalender kein *s* vor. Das tun wir viel lieber in den Schwein**s**braten, in den viele Deutsche stattdessen lieber ein *e* geben. Ein *e* gibt man in Österreich wiederum ins gesetzliche Halt**e**verbot. Keines von beiden (weder e noch s, und schon gar nicht *es*) würde aber ein Schweizer in einer Jahrzahl haben wollen.

Comment: @Em1: (Forts.) Daher würde ich mich nicht trauen, Fugenlaute, die mir persönlich seltsam vorkommen, gleich mal als Fehler zu brandmarken. Viel wahrscheinlicher ist nämlich, dass diese Version irgendwo im deutschen Sprachraum durchaus völlig korrekt ist.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Die Schweizer laden das in der *Jahrzahl* übrig gebliebene *s* dafür in den *Schnellzugswagen*. Wo sie das übrige *e* hintun, weiss ich nicht.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Natürlich ist der Satz richtig. *umziehen* darf man sehr wohl transitiv verwenden. Von den drei Beispielen, die der Duden für *umziehen* im Sinne von "Kleidung wechseln" angibt, lautet eines:

> Ein Kind festlich umziehen

(anscheinend ein gern genommenes Beispiel)

Comment: … vermutlich, weil Kinder sich nicht so gut dagegen wehren können. Ähnlich wie Pudel oder _Shopping Queen_-Kandidaten. ;-)

Comment: @PerlDog: Das hat weniger mit *sich dagegen wehren* als vielmehr mit *es noch nicht selber können* zu tun. Menschen, denen von anderen Menschen die Kleidung gewechselt wird, sind in der überwiegenden Mehrheit Kleinkinder. Die zweite, aber viel kleinere Gruppe sind Menschen, die körperlich beeinträchtigt sind.

Comment: Ich bitte um Entschuldigung, @HubertSchölnast. Du schreibst immer so gute Beiträge und ich habe wieder mal nur rumgeblödelt.

Comment: Ich finde allerdings "ein Kind festlich anziehen" besser und gebräuchlicher.